# Converting column data type from string to date with PySpark returns null values

Tags: apache-spark, date, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I was trying to change the datatype of a column (`Disponibility`) from string type to date, but every time it shows this column converted as null values (for example: 23/01/2022 becomes null ....)

This is my code:

```py
dfwdate = dfworkers2.withColumn("Disponibility", to_date("Disponibility")) \
.show(truncate=False)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You additionally need to supply the `date_format` with `to_date` , various format references can be found [Spark date pattern documentation page](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-datetime-pattern.html)

#### Date Conversion Examples

```
s = StringIO("""
date_str
2022-03-01
2022-05-20
2022-06-21
2022-10-22
""")

df = pd.read_csv(s,delimiter=',')

sparkDF = sql.createDataFrame(df)\
             .withColumn('date_parsed',F.to_date(F.col('date_str'), 'yyyy-MM-dd'))\
             .drop('date_str')

sparkDF.show()

+-----------+
|date_parsed|
+-----------+
| 2022-03-01|
| 2022-05-20|
| 2022-06-21|
| 2022-10-22|
+-----------+

sparkDF.printSchema()

root
 |-- date_parsed: date (nullable = true)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
to_date('Disponibility', 'dd/MM/yyyy')
```

You have correctly chosen the function `to_date`. It's just that in your case it requires another parameter - the actual format of your date string `'dd-MM-yyyy'`. By default, `to_date` expects to get the format `'yyyy-MM-dd'`. Since your column is not of this format, you get null returned.

Full example:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame([('23/01/2022',)], ['Disponibility'])

df.show()
# +-------------+
# |Disponibility|
# +-------------+
# |   23/01/2022|
# +-------------+
print(df.dtypes)
# [('Disponibility', 'string')]

df = df.withColumn('Disponibility', F.to_date('Disponibility', 'dd/MM/yyyy'))

df.show()
# +-------------+
# |Disponibility|
# +-------------+
# |   2022-01-23|
# +-------------+
print(df.dtypes)
# [('Disponibility', 'date')]
```